# vscode custom extension loading bar

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently creating a custom extension in VSCode. So far i managed to create a simple section for the sidebar like this(I created the robot icon on the bottom and added the buttons):

[image]

Now when i click a button it will take a few seconds to calulate the result. When the button gets pressed, visually nothing happens so far. I want the standart blue loading bar to be active while the function is running. For example, when i am commiting something with the git extension, this blue bar is active:

[image]

Does someone know how this can be achieved in general?

Comment: Have you looked at the `window.withProgress()` method?

Answer (score 0):

There is a full example extension that uses the `progress` functionality.  See [vscode extensions: progress sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/progress-sample/src/extension.ts).

```js
    context.subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand('extension.startTask', () => {
        window.withProgress({
            location: ProgressLocation.Notification,
            title: "I am long running!",
            cancellable: true
        },
```

More at the link above.  The `location` can take a `viewID`.

Also there is an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744162/836330.